# Error when using addChild twice in one function in NativeScript

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I am trying to dynamically create stackLayouts and add them to the existing scrollView but got an error:

```
JS ERROR TypeError: scrollView.addChild is not a function. (In 'scrollView.addChild(stackLayout)', 'scrollView.addChild' is undefined)
```

but by using console.log it sees both of them:

```
StackLayout(10) ScrollView<dates>@diary/diary-page.xml:4:7;
```

My code is:

```
input.forEach(function(entry) {
    const scrollView = page.getViewById("dates");
    var stackLayout = new StackLayout();
    stackLayout.className = 'date';
    var label = new Label();
    label.text = entry.Date;
    stackLayout.addChild(label);
    console.log(stackLayout + ' ' + scrollView);
    scrollView.addChild(stackLayout);
});
```

Can anybody help with this strange behaviour? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason here: [How to nest elements in dynamically created ScrollView?](https://github.com/NativeScript/docs/issues/1183)

"ScrollView is actually an implantation of ContentView so the right way to set it's content is by doing:

**scrollview.content = stacklayout**

Note: Only can only set a single content view. That's the reason there is not addChild method as it suggests multiple children are supported."

Answer (score 0):

What's the code of your `getViewById` function? It looks like it doesn't return DOM element, this is why you can't call `addChild` on `scrollView`.

Comment: Hi @luser is a standard function to get an element in NativeScript and when I do console.log it sees it ScrollView<dates>@diary/diary-page.xml:4:7;